# Harvester not working for google in kali

Tags: kali-linux

I tried to use harvester for google and other data sources such as google and Firefox and it didn't work but it worked for Bing.so i am confused if I am wrong or there is mistake in tool.

Comment: You need to explain fully what "_it didn't work_" message in your situation. Explain what you tried, what happened, what didn't happen that you think should have happened. Include messages and errors. Remember that we aren't with you seeing what you're doing so you have to tell us what you saw

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the 4.2.0 package version, you can't use google sources.

[TheHarverster on github.](https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester/releases/tag/4.2.0)

> All modules that use Google as there source to get the data due to Google blocking with capcha's has been removed.